# I am trying to write a function in C to sum two numbers, but I am not getting the expected answer

Tags: c, function

I've been trying to do a program which sums two numbers; I want to use a function to do that. The function is called "sum". With the code shown below I get "the sum is 0". What am I doing wrong?

```
#include <stdio.h>

int sum()

{
    int a, b;
    int answer;
    answer = a+b;
    return 0;
}

int main()
     {
        int var_a,  var_b;
        int result;

        printf (" first number \n");
        scanf ("%i",&var_a);
        printf ("second number \n");
        scanf ("%i",&var_b);
            result = sum(var_a,var_b);

        printf(" The sum is %i", result);

        return 0;       
     }
```

Comment: You `sum` function is always returning `0`.  You're setting `answer` but never using it.  Why not return `answer` instead of `0`?  Wouldn't that make more sense?

Comment: `int a = ..., b = ..., result = a + b;`

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are two problems with your function `sum`

First, the return value should be `answer`, not `0`, otherwise no matter how you call this function, it always gives you 0. So change `return 0;` to `return answer;`.

Second, you are clearly aware that function `sum` takes arguments from outside when you do: `result = sum(var_a,var_b);` in your `main`. So you should define your function `sum` accordingly like:

```
int sum(int a, int b)

{
    int answer;
    answer = a+b;
    return answer;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

```
int sum()
{
    int a, b;
    int answer;
    answer = a+b;
    return 0;
}
```

What does this function do? Let's see:

- Declares `a`, `b` and `answer` and does not assign values to them (so they could have any value, maybe 0, maybe 635621112).
- Sets `answer` to `a+b` - the sum of two garbage values is still a garbage value.
- Returns `0`.

So basically, it adds two unknown values, and then ignores the result of that and returns 0. It should be no surprise that it returns 0, when you wrote `return 0;`

If you want to make `a` and `b` be the parameters to your function, then the function should start like this:

```
int sum(int a, int b)
{
    int answer;
```

and if you want to return the value of `answer`, then change `return 0;` to `return answer;`

Comment: Doesn't return answer, returns 0. You may want to fix that.

Answer (score -1):

you can use user defined function, make sure about the datatypes that you are using for the variables
here is the simple example

```
int AddTwoNumbers(int a, int b)
{
    int result;
    result=a+b;
    return result;
}
```

now you can call that function in the main function

```
int main(){
  int a=10,b=20;
  printf("The sum is:%d", AddTwoNumbers(a,b));
  return 0;
}
```

Comment: This doesn't seem to add any value beyond the existing answers (from two years ago).